# How to dynamically select json object to be used in an Ansible task?

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to select which json object to use based on some dynamic criteria?

I have a yml file:

```
- name: Get data
  uri:
    url: "foo/get_data/{{item.name}}"
    return_content: yes
  with_items: "{{stuff_names}}"
  register: app_out

- name: Use data
  uri:
    url: "foo/use_data/item.json[0].id"
    method: POST
  with_items: "{{ app_out.results }}"
```

Where the call to `foo/get_data/<name>` returns a json array with 1 or 2 items:

Sample from `foo/get_data/bar1`:

> [{"id": 1, "type": "x"},{"id": 2, "type": "y"}]

Sample from `foo/get_data/bar2`:

> [{"id": 1, "type": "x"}]

In the "Use data" task is there a way to specify which json object in the array to use based on if an object exists in `item` or the size of `item` etc?  Right now its hard coded to the first object `item.json[0]`.

For example, 
if `item` contains an object of type "y" then use that object, otherwise use `item` of type "x".

or
if size of `item` is > 1, use `item` of type "x".

EDIT:

Or perhaps even a separate ansible task to prune the registered app_out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *"if item contains an object of type "y" then use that object, otherwise use item of type "x"*

A: The play below implements this logic, I think.

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    results:
      - {"id": 1, "type": "x"}
      - {"id": 2, "type": "y"}
      - {"id": 3, "type": "z"}
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_list: "{{ results|
                     selectattr('type', 'defined')|
                     selectattr('type', 'equalto','y')|list }}"
    - set_fact:
        my_list: "{{ results|
                     selectattr('type', 'defined')|
                     selectattr('type', 'equalto','x')|list }}"
      when: my_list|length == 0
    - name: Use type y, otherwise use type x
      debug:
        var: my_list
```

gives

```
"my_list": [
    {
        "id": 2, 
        "type": "y"
    }
]
```